# Why reading from a linux module works character by character but not for whole string

Tags: c, linux, string, linux-kernel

I have my kernel module's read function as follows. It simply reads a single character from kernel buffer and copies it into user buffer. 
Once I have reached the end of kernel buffer, I return 0. This works perfectly.

```
static ssize_t debugfs_read(struct file *f, char __user *buf,
    size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{
    ssize_t rc = 0;

    pr_info("%s.\n", "In read");

    rc = copy_to_user(buf, &kbuffer[*offset], 1);



    if (rc < 0)
        return -EFAULT;

    if (kbuffer[*offset] == '\0')
        return 0;

    *offset = *offset + 1;

    return 1;
}
```

**Now If I try to copy the whole kernel buffer in one go into the user buffer,
 the module does not print anything.**

*Why is that? The code in this case:*

```
static ssize_t debugfs_read(struct file *f, char __user *buf,
    size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{
    ssize_t rc = 0;

    pr_info("%s.\n", "In read");

    rc = copy_to_user(buf, &kbuffer, BUFF_LEN);


    if (rc != 0)
        return -EFAULT;

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

On using the accepted answer's solution, I realized that `read` is called twice by kernel. Here is `strace`:

```
read(3, "s03324135655\0", 65536)        = 13
write(1, "s03324135655\0", 13)          = 13
read(3, "", 65536)                      = 0
```

Why is that? Is it because we *must* return 0 once we are done `reading` from a module? The second system call has an empty string essentially stipulating that there is nothing left to read and we should return zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you are given a length with a buffer, you need to use it. You wouldn't want to stomp on some other user-space memory if the buffer provided is smaller than your kernel buffer.
2. You need to return the number of bytes that you copied to the buffer. Your character-by-character code returned `1`, but your code for copying the entire buffer always returned `0` in the success case, which tells the caller you wrote `0` bytes to the buffer.
3. You need to take into account the offset parameter as well.

So, rather than implementing all this logic yourself, just use `simple_read_from_buffer`, which does this for you:

```
static ssize_t debugfs_read(struct file *f, char __user *buf,
    size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{
    return simple_read_from_buffer(buf, length, offset, &kbuffer, BUFF_LEN);
}
```

Comment: In my case, I get random values for length, I guess this is kernel's prerogative. But I have a question. In the single character function, I return `0` on completion, but here you return the actual length. What should I *actually* return? Character by character copy works fine.

Comment: The number of bytes written to the provided buffer. But if you're getting "random" values for length, then you must have done something wrong somewhere in code you have not shown.

Comment: Please see the end of the answer for what is probably the correct way to do it: Using a built-in function which does what you were attempting to do.

Comment: When I use `simple_read_from_buffer`, the kernel calls `debug_fs` read twice, instead of only once time. Why is that?

Comment: Okay I am updating the question with more details.

Comment: Why do you think it should only be called once? When reading data, the kernel doesn't know how big the data stream is. It will continue calling read until read returns 0 or an error. This is the only way the caller knows the length of the data. You might have seen this pattern in a user-space application calling `read`. This is just the other side of that interface.